# What tools would people recommend for looking at gcc/linux object files?

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I want to look at the code generated by the g++/gcc compiler on linux. I'm assuming there are tools that can reverse engineer .o files and let me look at what's in there at a level a bit higher then machine instructions?
I may also be missing a compiler option to simply generate something human readable before the object files are compiled? If so what is this compiler option?

Comment: I believe -S is the usual option for assembly language output, which will be a lot more useful to you than the .o files.

Comment: What are you looking for? gcc can produce assembly output with the -S flag but you want something "on a higher level"?

Comment: Please remember that when you turn on various optimization options (i.e -O1, -O2, etc) it's much harder to make sense of the disassembly

Answer (score 6):

Do you want something like objdump (part of binutils)? That will disassemble code for you, and if there are debug symbols left, it'll show them too.

Comment: The whole binutils kit is your friend here. You can use strings to search for printable strings inside an .o file and use nm to list symbols from object files.

Comment: And for AT&T syntax haters: `objdump -M=intel-mnemonic,intel -r -d test.o` will disassemble using intel-style syntax. For some reason, both `intel-mnemonic` and `intel` need to be specified (in spite of the docs saying otherwise). It also has to be before the `-d` option.

Answer (score 6):

The gcc options `-S -fverbose-asm` cause it to output assembly language with annotations in comments.